# Generate random message from a list

Tags: python, list, random

I'm using this Python code to pick 3 words to form a message from the 5 words randomly.

```
def randomMessage():    
    word = ['Animal', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Queen', 'Bird']

    return (random.sample(word, 3))
```

and then, in a later part of the code, I want to put this in a message using

```
" + randomMessage() + "
```

but it gives me an error saying "must be str, not a list".

How can I fix this?

Comment: " + str(randomMessage()) + "

Comment: @smoggers, bad advice.

Comment: I am 100000% sure this is a duplicate of many under different masks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [**`str.join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on the `list`.

Calling `random.sample(word, 3)` returns a `list`, so to convert it to a `string`, with spaces between every element, you need to do something like:

```
' '.join(random.sample(word, 3))
```

which would give:

```
>>> ' '.join(random.sample(word, 3))
'Bird Dog Cat'
```

---

So, to complete the answer, you would need to modify the line at the end of your `randomMessage()` function, making the whole thing:

```
def randomMessage():
    word = ['Animal', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Queen', 'Bird']
    return ' '.join(random.sample(word, 3))
```

and some tests show that it now returns a `string`:

```
>>> randomMessage()
'Animal Queen Bird'
>>> randomMessage()
'Cat Dog Animal'
>>> randomMessage()
'Animal Cat Bird'
>>> randomMessage()
'Bird Dog Animal'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a list, not a string. The quickest way to fix it

```
return " ".join(random.sample(word, 3))
```

Or you can make it more explicit

```
def random_message(): 
  words = ['Animal', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Queen', 'Bird']
  three_words = random.sample(words, 3)
  return " ".join(three_words)
```

Note: use this style in Python: `random_message`, not camelcase `randomMessage`